# Understanding how ruby methods are invoked

Tags: ruby, function, methods

I have a java background. I came up with a method in ruby which can be invoked as

```
Oj::Doc.open('[1,2,3]')
```

as well as

```
Oj::Doc.open('[1,2,3]') { |doc| doc.size() }
```

The first is similar to java method, but I don't understand what's happening in 2nd case. Can some one give me some clarification on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in Ruby is an Object. Below is an example of `block`. Block is nothing else but a block again.

```
 { |doc| doc.size() }
```

A method in ruby can accepts any number of arguments, and the arguments are nothing but objects. So passing a block to a method is just like passing an object to a method.

```
def a_method(arg)
  return arg + yield(arg) if block_given?
  arg
end
a_method(3) #=> 3
a_method(3) { |x| x + 4 } #=> 10
```

In above example, `block_given?` evaluates to `true` if a block is supplied. `yield` evaluates the block in context of `self`. `self` is nothing but current object. The block is evaluated and a closure can be passed to block (above, as `x`) which is evaluated and returned back to `a_method`.

Proving that block is an object is fairly easy with a special [`&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Proc.html) operator:

```
def return_block(&block)
  block
end
return_block { |x, y| x + y }
#=> #<Proc:0x007fe28b53aa50@(pry):65>
```

`Proc` is object representation of a block.
In first example, you saw that a block was not explicitly mentioned in arguments list of `a_method`, but was available with special `yield` keyword. `&block` is the way to acquire the block as argument.

The first example can be re-written as following:

```
def a_method(arg, &block)
  return arg + block.call(arg) if block
  arg
end

a_method(3) #=> 3
a_method(3) { |x| x + 4 } #=> 10
```

Another way to create block object:

```
block = Proc.new { |x| x + 4 }
# Similarly, you can pass the block (object) as explicit argument
a_method(3, &block)
```

For your original question, you can also do:

```
block = Proc.new { |doc| doc.size() }
Oj::Doc.open('[1,2,3]', &block)
```

This enables you to manage blocks, objects and methods dynamically.

Pure awesome Ruby. <3

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a block to a method.  A block is a closure that contains executable lines.

Blocks can be defined with a `do` `end` or with curly braces `{}` you've seen the curly braces version, here's the alternative...

```
Oj::Doc.open('[1,2,3]') do |doc| 
  doc.size()  
end
```

Not all methods need a block, but if it's passed it can be executed within the method using the `yield` keyword.  They can also be converted into Procs or Lambdas which are objects (a plain block is not an object)

If the block takes one or more arguments, they're passed within the vertical bars.  In this example...

```
[1, 2, 3].each { |number| print number }
```

... the block will be yielded to three times, once for each element in the array, and the array element is referenced by the `number` argument..

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, every method can take a block.  Your 2nd form of code has an unnamed block being passed to the method, in addition to the arguments that you are passing in the 1st form of your code.

Many methods do not do anything with a block.  But this will not cause an error.  This method, if it actually uses the block, will call `yield` to evaluate the block from within the method.

When a Ruby method uses a block, it may look like this:

```
def ruby_method
  yield if block_given?
end
```

This example uses an 'anonymous' block and the yield returns control to the program from where the `ruby_method` was called.